# get modifiers on windows platform

Tags: windows, events, user-interface

Anyone knows how to get modifier on Windows platform?

I know there is a function called **GetKeyState()**, but I could not get **windows** or **meta** key with it. [Its document is here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Any advices will apperciate.
Thx

Comment: Did you try the `VK_LWIN` and `VK_RWIN` virtual keys with `GetKeyState()`? What "meta" key are you referring to?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I follow your advice and get the windows key status successfully. The "meta" key I mean is the one between "Right Ctrl" and "Right Alt".

Answer (score 1):

The Windows key is covered by VK_LWIN and VK_RWIN, respectively the left and the right key.

The "meta" key is presumably the one that brings up the context menu for the active window, same one you'd see if you right-click the mouse.  It is VK_APPS.  Beware that it is not a modifier key.